# Docker: Permission denied when PHP upload file to mounted data volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume, docker-volume

I'm using docker quickstart terminal on **Win10**.

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce, 
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

I have a simple document upload php script that saves an uploaded document to a file location called '/uploads'.

I want to make the '/uploads' folder a volume attached to the php:apache container, so i can easily share the contents with the python back-end.

I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml` file to build a web service with a python back-end. 
**Note:** The php works on the `php:apache` environment without the volume.

```
$ docker volume create fileul --opt o=uid=197609,gid=0

version: '3.2'

services:
  Python_app:
    build: ./product
    volumes:
      - ./product:/usr/src/app
ports:
  - 5001:80

website:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./website:/var/www/html
      - type: volume
        source: fileuld
        target: /var/www/html/uploads
        read_only: false
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - Python_app

volumes:
  fileuld:
```

I get a **permission error on the web service** when I try to upload a document to the attached volume fileuld. `failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/upload.php`

I have read some other stackoverflow posts on this and they talk about uid and gid and i have tried using :

```
$ls -ls
```

Which gives the following:

```
 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ASUSNJHOME 197609 343 Sep 23 14:49 docker-compose.yml
32 drwxr-xr-x 1 ASUSNJHOME 197609   0 Sep 22 07:10 product/
 0 drwxr-xr-x 1 ASUSNJHOME 197609   0 Sep 23 15:38 volume-example/
 0 drwxr-xr-x 1 ASUSNJHOME 197609   0 Sep 22 21:32 website/
```

But i can't work out how to have the volume able to accept a document getting written into or how to change the permissions of it when it is being created from the docker-compose file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: what is output of `whoami` command?

Comment: what is the output of `id` and `ls -alh /var/www/html/` inside the `website` container

Comment: @TarunLalwani  

$ whoami
ASUSNJHOME

$ id
uid=197609(ASUSNJHOME) gid=197609 groups=197609

Comment: @VladoDemcak, $ whoami ASUSNJHOME

Comment: @TarunLalwani how do you do an `ls -alh /var/www/html/ ` inside a container? do you bin/bash in?

Comment: You would run `docker-compose exec website id` and `docker-compose exec website ls -alh /var/www/html/`

Comment: @TarunLalwani `$ docker-compose exec website id: 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)` and i just cant get the other command to work properly `$ docker-compose exec website ls -alh /var/www/html/
ls: cannot access C:/Program Files/Git/var/www/html/: No such file or directory`. Is it supposed to look at the git program folder on my local drive?

Comment: What is the current directory where the compose file is located?

Comment: @TarunLalwani `C:\Users\ASUSNJHOME\Desktop\tutorial`, when i run the commnd im in that directory in the docker terminal

Comment: Not sure what could be happening here.

Comment: @TarunLalwani, thanks for trying to help me out :)

Comment: @TarunLalwani is there an easier way to share data between docker containers? Its always going to be one file named 'File.pdf'

Comment: Why don't you just copy it inside the Dockerfile?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the File upload is a user interaction and happens after the dockerfile is composed, so it doesn't exist when the containers are created.